# How can I pass a delegated mutableVariable to a Compose function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to pass the MutableState variable over another function. The below is all good. But I don't like the `myMutableState.value`

```
@Composable
fun Func() {
    val myMutableState = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    Column {
        AnotherFunc(mutableValue = myMutableState)
        Text(if (myMutableState.value) "Stop" else "Start")
    }
}

@Composable
fun AnotherFunc(mutableValue: MutableState<Boolean>) {
}
```

So I decided to use `val myMutableState by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }`, as shown below. I no longer need to use `myMutableState.value` as shown below.

Unfortunately, the below won't compile. This is because I cannot pass it over the function `AnotherFunc(mutableValue = myMutableState)`

```
@Composable
fun Func() {
    val myMutableState by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    Column {
        AnotherFunc(mutableValue = myMutableState) // Error here
        Text(if (myMutableState) "Stop" else "Start")
    }
}

@Composable
fun AnotherFunc(mutableValue: MutableState<Boolean>) {
}
```

How can I still use `by` and still able to pass the MutableState over the function?

Comment: What's being tried above is an anti-pattern, and should be avoided. It's great that the By Variable Delegate helped expose it. https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/how-kotlin-by-variable-delegate-helps-me-avoid-anti-pattern-558004000341?sk=2f28b25141c2eb38b6991d29b92e901d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

=-0987our composable function should just take a boolean:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AnotherFunc(mutableValue: Boolean) {
}
```

Not sure why your composable function (AnotherFun) needs to have a mutable state. The calling function (Fun) will automatically recompose when the value changes, triggering recomposition of AnotherFun.

Comment: What if I want to assign it a new value? Since it's suppsoed to be mutable

Comment: I am also stuck here. Because in such cases, I have to assign a new value to my mutablestate value and I don't want to use lambda expression here.

Comment: @MikkelT and Abdullah, see my answer below.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The name of the function parameter is `mutableValue`, yet it's not mutable. With your solution you can not change the value of `mutableValue` within `AnotherFunc` 

Answer (score 1):

While Johann's solution works for OP's specific scenario, to be able to assign the passed parameter another value, you'd need a Lambda function for each change, like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AnotherFunc(mutableValue: Boolean, onMutableValueChange: (Boolean) -> Unit){
    onMutableValueChange(false) // myMutableState would now also be false
}

@Composable
fun Func() {
    val myMutableState by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    Column {
        AnotherFunc(mutableValue = myMutableState, onMutableValueChange = {myMutableState = it})
    }
}
```

`(Boolean) -> Unit` means a function that accepts a Boolean as a parameter and doesn't have a return value. Simply pass a lambda function to change `mutableValue` as seen in the example above, and call it in `AnotherFunc` whenever you need to change `mutableValue`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer solves OP's problem, but that's not the question OP had originally asked. Ty.