# How to do state hoist of two or three levels?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, hoisting

Imagine a composable A that haves a lower composable B that haves a even lower composable C with haves some buttons.

The buttons must change a state remember variable stored in composable A. The state hoist theory tells you that you must pass, for each button, the variable value and the lambda function that modifies the state variable in two parameters from A to B, then, from B to C. But if there are 10 buttons, you will need to pass a lot of lambdas and parameters, it seems to be overprogramming and very complex.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

This is a sample code similar to that A B C hierarchy, in which the `Button` composables needs to change the state var `currentImageModel` in the main composable `ImagePortfolio`

```
@Composable
fun ImagePortfolio(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val currentImageModel by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(24.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        ImageHolder(
            ImageModelProvider.imageModelList[currentImageModel].imageResource,
            modifier.weight(0.75f).wrapContentSize()
        )
        Column(
            modifier.weight(0.25f).fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp, Alignment.Bottom),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            DescriptionHolder(
                ImageModelProvider.imageModelList[currentImageModel].imageDescription,
                ImageModelProvider.imageModelList[currentImageModel].imageAuthor,
                ImageModelProvider.imageModelList[currentImageModel].imageYear.toString()
            )
            ButtonsHolder()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ImageHolder(imageResource: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = imageResource),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = modifier
            .border(BorderStroke(16.dp, Color.White))
            .padding(16.dp)
            .shadow(elevation = 20.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun DescriptionHolder(description: String, author: String, year: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column (
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.8f)
            .background(colorResource(R.color.description_background))
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = description
        )
        Row (
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.Start)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = author,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
            Text(
                text = "($year)"
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ButtonsHolder(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row (
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
            .padding(4.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ){
        Button(R.string.previous, {}, Modifier.width(120.dp))
        Button(R.string.next, {}, Modifier.width(120.dp))
    }
}

@Composable
fun Button(textResource: Int, function: (()-> Unit), modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Button(
        modifier = modifier,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = colorResource(id = R.color.button_color)),
        onClick = function
    ) {
        Text(text = stringResource(id = textResource))
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the ways you could achieve this is found in this question. The question itself has the answer. You could pass mutableState object down the compose hierarchy and mutate it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696273/how-can-i-pass-a-delegated-mutablevariable-to-a-compose-function

Comment: @RaviRaj please read carefully my question, I already know that.. but it's not the thing i'm asking here

Comment: That solution would have saved you from sending lamdas, but you should anyway send mutableState Object. If you don't want to send any params but access the state in deeply nested child, then probably you have try something like CompositionLocalProvider where you send this mutableState, but I have not tried this.

Comment: @RaviRaj passing the mutable state down is an ugly anti pattern and completely defeats the purpose of hoisting state, i.e. encapsulation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's considered anti pattern in Android and unidirectional data flow, but iOS SwiftUI heavily uses binding to state variables and send these binding as params. But there are some syntax level help from SwiftUI. Sometimes its ok to use ugly pattern if its solves the problem of DRY :P.  At last, If you don't like any of the techniques, there is one all purpose thing, Singletonsssss. Ha ha

Comment: @Tenfour04 please can you tell me how you can solve this question? thanks

Answer (score 0):

lambdas functions can trigger recomposition. it's better use a "data class" with "remembers" to avoid it.

actions class contains all event and listeners of screen.

```
data class PortfolioActions(
    val previous: () -> Unit = {},
    val next: () -> Unit = {},
    val onClick: () -> Unit = {}
)

@Composable
fun rememberExchangeCBUDetailActions(
    viewModel: ViewModel
): PortfolioActions =
    remember {
        PortfolioActions(
            previous = viewmodel::doSomething()
        )
    }

@Composable
fun ButtonsHolder(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    actions: PortfolioActions
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
            .padding(4.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Button(R.string.previous, actions.previous, Modifier.width(120.dp))
        Button(R.string.next, actions.next, Modifier.width(120.dp))
    }
}

@Composable
fun Button(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textResource: Int,
    actions: PortfolioActions
) {
    Button(
        modifier = modifier,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = colorResource(id = R.color.button_color)),
        onClick = actinons.onClick
    ) {
        Text(text = stringResource(id = textResource))
    }
}
```

About DescriptionHolder you can use a immutable class

```
data class Description (
  val description: String,
  val author: String, 
  val year: String
)

@Composable
fun DescriptionHolder(description: Description, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {}
```

Important use "val" and not "var"

Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability

and good practices

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVVFhyuVV5g

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think I would use an enum to represent the possible button clicks. Then only one click listener has to be hoisted up.

```
enum class PortfolioClick {
    Next, Previous
}
```

```
@Composable
fun ImagePortfolio(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val currentImageModel by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(24.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        ImageHolder(
            ImageModelProvider.imageModelList[currentImageModel].imageResource,
            modifier.weight(0.75f).wrapContentSize()
        )
        Column(
            modifier.weight(0.25f).fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp, Alignment.Bottom),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            DescriptionHolder(
                ImageModelProvider.imageModelList[currentImageModel].imageDescription,
                ImageModelProvider.imageModelList[currentImageModel].imageAuthor,
                ImageModelProvider.imageModelList[currentImageModel].imageYear.toString()
            )
            ButtonsHolder {
                when (it) {
                    PortfolioClick.Previous -> // do something
                    PortfolioClick.Next -> // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...

@Composable
fun ButtonsHolder(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, clickListener: (PortfolioClick)->Unit = {}) {
    Row (
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
            .padding(4.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ){
        Button(R.string.previous, { clickListener(PortfolioClick.Previous) }, Modifier.width(120.dp))
        Button(R.string.next, { clickListener(PortfolioClick.Next) }, Modifier.width(120.dp))
    }
}

// ...
```

Comment: The code works, but believe me, I can't understand how it works. Can't understand how that when (it) inside that single ButtonsHolder can paint the two buttons, how that 'it' is assigned to each etc... Also, it seems to be a very complex to understand solution for me. Please, can you explain how that when (it) works? I wonder if there is another simpler solution... maybe using viewmodel or something. For sure I'm very grateful for trying to offer a solution, but I really don't like this solution. I prefeer to put more arguments because this seems to be too much complex for this purpose.

Comment: I mean that I know how 'it' works on other situations, but not in this

Comment: It’s no different than in any other situation. The listener has a single parameter so you can call it `it` as a shortcut. The parameter tells you which button the click originated from. You’re assigning the parameter down in the Button Container. This is elementary lambda stuff. Once you’re used to Kotlin it will be trivial to you. A ViewModel would be inappropriate (it’s not supposed to know anything about UI or there will be UI leaks) and turn your code into spaghetti, much worse than your original solution.